Blazor Server - User doesn't log in
I have a Blazor app with "InteractiveServer" render mode. After I re-deploy application - strange things happen: despite of cookies still exists (checked developer tools tab Application/Cookies) application behave like user logged out (AuthorizeView works like not authorized). Even when user try to login, it still work the same. But when I manually remove cookies - login works normally.
I tried to add clear cookie logic, but it doesn't help at all. Below placed code from my LoginComponent
await JsInterop.ClearAuth();

var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
var apiUrl = ApiConfig.ApiEndpointBaseUrl + "/account/login";
var result = await client.PostResultAsJsonAsync<LoginResult, LoginModel>(apiUrl, Model);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    if (result.Value?.Succeeded ?? false)
    {
        await AuthenticationStateProvider.Login(Model.Email);
        await JsInterop.WriteAuth(result);

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.BaseUri, true);
    }
}

Any ideas how to fix it?
EDIT
.WriteAuth(result);
.ClearAuth();

This 2 methods is extensions, that modify document.cookie
